# How do I access hidden superclass member using subclass object

Tags: java, inheritance

Is there any way to acess a superclass member hidden by a subclass member using object of subclass in another class.

```
public class A {
    int i, j;

    A() {
        i = 5;
        j = 5;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    int i;

    B() {
        super();
        i = 10;
    }
}

class TestEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B obj = new B();
        // i from B
        System.out.println(obj.i);
    }
}
```

i need to acess i from A in testEx using obj.. 
same doubt is present in the case of non-static inner class.. anyway to acess variable of OuterClass in InnerClass with same name that of one in InnerClass

Answer (score 5):

As simple as `((A)this).i` from within the class `B`'s instance methods or, even simpler,

```
A obj = new B(); 
System.out.println(obj.i);
```

Why? Because nothing except instance methods is subject to dynamic binding and overriding. The class `B` has all the instance variables of its ancestors.

Comment: Well i could use super from within class B right..? i need to do it in TextEx. I know assigning subclass reference to superclass variable. I believe i from superclass will be present in obj. I need to get that

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
                  B obj=new B();
                //i from B
                 System.out.println(((A)obj).i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Expose your classes get methods via polymorphism to get the value of A's i from the instance invoked by B object. This is what you topic title is implying.
2. provide public get/set methods in both classes, then sit still relax and call it up.